# Now You're Packing with Portals #1

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, polyomino

I was staring at my window last night, and daydreaming (nightdreaming?) about filling it with shapes. Suddenly, I was struck with inspiration for a new type of puzzle! Here's a fairly easy instance:

[image: polyominoes 1]

Pack the colored polyominoes into the white area, *without* rotating them, so that they fill it perfectly.

What's that? The green piece can't fit, you say? Oh right, I forgot to mention: **The gray walls are portals.** Any piece that would normally overlap a gray wall goes through it entirely, as if there were no space there at all. The gray border around the puzzle loops, as well - pieces that would stick off the right side of the board reappear at the left, and so on.

---

To demonstrate, here's an example packing:

[image: polyominoes 2]

Notice how the blue block warps from C1 to C3, across the wall at C2.

Comment: What happens if the center of the green piece overlaps the middle portal?

Comment: This is very cool!

Comment: @MatthewWells The piece simply won't fit. Each *edge* of the wall acts as a teleporter to the opposite side, but the actual *interior* of the wall is just solid.

Comment: As an aside, the best implementation of pentomino puzzles I've seen is in an old (but still living!) game called Puzzle Pirates. The "Carpentry" duty station which was used to keep your ship from falling apart was pure pentomino fun where you'd have to fit one of three given shapes into one of four puzzles without neglecting any of them for too long. Extra points for clearing a puzzle with the same tiled piece or by keeping the "Grain" of a patch job the same (never rotating a piece only 90 degrees)

Comment: For any future puzzles: theres a bit of confusion about the answer, and how the portal works. In the answer, the whole of the left side of the red gets transported, suggesting that the portal teleports all connected cells (you can kinda see this with the white outline in the example. I'd recommend clarifying this so people don't get confused. Great puzzle though!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This works! (I think)

> [image]

(Hopefully that’s clear enough how the shapes go)

I got this mostly by thinking about how the blue and red can be placed such that the top and bottom of the green can be transported up and down without overlapping.

Brilliant idea! Hope to see some more!

Comment: How can B3 or E3 phase through without a portal along row 3?

Comment: @personjerry the portal splits the red shape into 2. The whole left side of the red shifts to the left, not just one cell

Comment: I agree that's the only way it's solvable, but that's not consistent with the puzzle description. Only pieces that overlap grey areas wrap, it says nothing about attached blocks moving

Comment: @Mohirl true, it could probably be clarified in the question. As you say, this is the only solution so it must be true, just needs to be made clear from the start

Comment: I'm at a complete loss for what is and isn't allowed in the middle grey box given the comments on OP and this accepted solve. Why is red allowed to interact this way, but green couldn't be placed one row lower? (Not by the logic to solve, but by the rules of the puzzle)

Comment: Green couldn't be placed one row lower, because a green block can't be on top of the grey area. If you have five green squares that are legally placed, then you can ask the question "do the portals connect them into the shape of an r-pentomino?" just like in this picture, we have five legally-placed red squares, and the portal connects them into the shape of a u-pentomino.

Comment: @MishaLavrov but... you could have a green placement there in which the portals, as described, do connect it to be the same shape as provided. Not that solves the puzzle, but there's no logical exclusion provided. Green could be in C1,B2,D2,C3,D3(portal is on middle piece going up), D1,A2,B2,D2,C3(portal is on middle piece going left) or D1,B2,D2,E2,C3(portal is on middle piece going right) as it's currently described. There's another possible iteration if the middle piece can go down and force the lower piece through the portal below to push it back to the top (C1,D1,B2,D2,C3)

Comment: @TCooper I don't see how C1, B2, D2, C3, D3 could make the green piece. Aside from the normal C3-D3 and D2-D3 adjacencies, B2 is adjacent to D2 through a portal, and C1 could be adjacent through C3 through one of two portals, making either a P pentomino with a weird slice through it, or a square tetromino with one corner "doubled up".

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> ```
> B G G G B
> B R . R R
> B R G G R
> ```

Thought process:

> I figured that the three pieces cannot make up the required number of cells for each column, at least without a piece going through the center gray cell horizontally. There are five ways to horizontally go through the center gray cell, so I tried one by one until the column sum became feasible.

And indeed it's an interesting kind of a puzzle I've never seen before. Nice job.